# Xcode error: "expected expression" after upgrade Xcode from 7 to 9

Tags: xcode, expression

I encountered a very strange thing.

The code is ok and well compiled in Xcode 7.

But after I upgrade Xcode from 7 to 9.

The following codes show "expected expression" error

```
if ([jsonDic objectForKey:@"errMsg"] !=nil 
    && ![[jsonDic objectForKey:@"errMsg"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self showAlertView:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertMsgErrorTitle", @"") 
            and:[[jsonDic objectForKey:@"errMsg"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
else{
        [self showAlertView:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertMsgErrorTitle", @"") 
            and:[UserSetting getString:@"NSLocalizedDescription"]];
}
```

It shows "expected expression" with red underline for the "colon" following "and" as following graph.

[image]

I can't get it, don't know what to fix.

Did the code syntax changed from 7 to 9?

Any idea how to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add a space character after `!=` (In Swift the compiler complains about it)

Comment: the error still exists :'(

Answer (score 0):

The `and` is keyword in objectC, so we should not use is as the method argument name.

After I change the name of `and` to `andContent` and replace all in project, everything goes well.

And I don't know why the old version of Xcode compiled without any problem.